# inotify not firing notifications on file modification

Tags: c++, linux, filesystems, inotify

I have been tweaking the example [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-ubuntu-inotify/index.html) to make it repeatedly watch a file for 'modifications'. My code is [here](http://pastebin.com/tK83Fx5X). In my tests the inotify notification is only firing the first time the file is 'modified'(i.e. `touch`'ed). Any subsequent modifications to the file are not causing any notifications to fire. `stat` shows that the 'Modify' time has changed. Also, modifying the code to remove the watch and re-add each time a notification fires(i.e. move `inotify_add_watch` and `inotify_rm_watch` to be inside the `while(1)` loop in my [sample](http://pastebin.com/tK83Fx5X)) did not help resolve this issue.

I was wondering if any one here could help with what I may be doing wrong. Also, although I have added a watch for `IN_ALL_EVENTS`, I really only care about `IN_MODIFY` events. Not sure if that makes any difference.

Also, does this use case not work? Should I change my approach to watch the directory instead? Please advice.

TIA.

Edit 1: As noted by [themel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15231268/391113), the handling of `i` needed some fixing. However even the fixed version is not firing notifications for subsequent filesystem 'events'. Also, adding a watch on the directory as opposed to the file is exhibiting similar non-deterministic behavior.

Edit 2: I would like to get this [asio + inotify example](http://pastebin.com/v7HEabjv) based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12274214/391113) to work. Unfortunately that example hasn't been working for me at all. Any help would be much appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After themel's fix, your code works fine when watching a directory, in my tests. When watching a file, `event->len` is zero, and your code ignores the notifications.

With the test for `event->len` removed and all `event->name` replaced by `file_path` in the printf statements, it works fine when watching a file as well.

PS: Just noticed you mention `touch`.

`touch` sends the following events:

```
IN_OPEN
IN_ATTRIB
IN_CLOSE_WRITE
```

no IN_MODIFY

Also, don't test modification by editing it with `vim` as I just did - it deletes the file while shuffling the working copy and the swap, which removes the watch. `pico` works.

Comment: Although I wonder why `touch` does not cause an `IN_MODIFY` notification. `stat` seems to suggest `touch` has modified the `Modify` time of the file.

Comment: IN_MODIFY refers to actual modifications to the file data. Time is part of meta-data, which is an attribute of the file system.

Comment: Appreciate the vim comment.  Was smacking my head against that one.

Answer (score 3):

Your handling of `i` is broken, you never reset it to 0 in the loop. This causes any later inotify events to be considered only when they are longer than the longest event before them, which is not likely what you want.

[Fixed version](http://pastebin.com/F1DimeDM).

Comment: You're right. The handling of `i` was certainly broken - thanks for catching that. However even the fixed version seems to miss later notifications(after the first notification fires). Any thoughts on fixing this?

Comment: Hm, I keep getting inotify events with that code (but none of your conditions fire because a) when watching an individual file, event->name will always be empty and b) touch will give you IN_ATTRIB events, not IN_MODIFY).

Answer (score 1):

when monitoring an individual file event->len will be 0 because the file name is not returned.  I noticed a lot of the example programs have this issue.